# Prove $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\{(p,q)\in T\times T,p!q!=n\}|=6$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, factorial, limsup-and-liminf

Let $T$ be the set of nonnegative integers, I need to prove that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\{(p,q)\in T\times T,p!q!=n\}|=6$$

It's really easy to show that

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\{(p,q)\in T\times T,p!q!=n\}|\ge6$$
since for $n>2$
$$(n!)!=0!(n!)!=1!(n!)!=n!(n!-1)!=(n!-1)!n!=(n!)!1!=(n!)!0!$$

So I'm looking for a way to prove the apposite inequality.

Comment: maybe this link can help :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991728/equal-products-of-consecutive-integers

Comment: A generalization for  your equation $n!(n!-1)!=(n!)!$ may be :
$$a!(\frac{a!}{b!}-1)!=\frac{a!}{b!}!b!$$  for $a\geq b$

Comment: The problem here is related to solving the equation $p!q!=r!s!$, and this equation can be simplified in all cases to one of the form $\frac{q!}{r!}=\frac{s!}{p!}$ which rises the problem of EQUAL PRODUCTS OF CONSECUTIVE INTEGER and this problem was conjectured to have only finite solution by Erdos and was confirmed in this paper http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.25.727

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This equality was proved by Daniel M. Kane in [this paper](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dakane/Factorials.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much and also Daniel. Do you know him?

Comment: No, I don't know him, I was working in your problem and one of my friends told me that he have seen this problem somewhere else and so i made a research and I found it, good luck!